# What's the way to check if all the elements in an array are nil?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I would like to know if there's anything except `nil` values in an array.

```
arr = [nil, nil, nil, nil] # => true
arr = [nil, 45, nil, nil] # => false
```

There could be any values of any types (not only `45`).

Comment: _"There could be any values"_ – does that include `false` and should it be treated like any other non-nil value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use [#any?](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/any%3F) method for array

```
[nil, 45].any?
=> true
[nil, nil].any?
=> false
```

From the documentation:

> If the block is not given, Ruby adds an implicit block of {|obj| obj} (that is any? will return true if at least one of the collection members is not false or nil.

Note: This won't work if `false` boolean values are present.

```
[nil, false].any?
=> false # It should return `true`
```

Other options would be:

```
arr = [nil, nil, 45]
arr.count(nil) == arr.length
=> false

(arr - [nil]).empty?
=> false
```

Comment: Try it with an array with `false` objects.

Comment: It won't work if `false` values are present

Comment: All the answers work, but this is the most suitable in my opinion.

Answer (score 13):

Use the [`Enumerable#all?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) method:

```
p arr.all? { |x| x.nil? }
```

Or

```
p arr.all?(&:nil?)
```

As @Stefan suggested,

```
 p arr.all?(NilClass) #works only for Ruby 2.5
```

Comment: This would iterate through all the elements to check if they are not nil so if there are 1000's of elements it might not be efficient

Comment: @Subash, AFAIK `all?` will stop on first not nil value.

Comment: also `all(&:nil?)`

Comment: @llya yes, that's an other way.

Comment: @llya yes but what if there are 10000 nil values, it'd iterate through all of them

Comment: @Subash how does `compact` works? It should iterate as well, otherwise what's the other way to check everything is nil?

Comment: @Rajagopalan apparently compact uses iteration too, so its basically the same thing I guess, but a different way to write :)

Comment: `all?(NilClass)` would work as well (requires Ruby 2.5+)

Comment: @Stefan which Ruby version you have? I am getting this error `all?': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)`

Comment: @Stefan Okay, I am using 2.4

Comment: You should add Stefan's suggestion to your answer and explain how it works.

Comment: @SagarPandya Added!

Comment: @Stefan fallback for Ruby2.5- would be `all?(&NilClass.method(:===))` which is what `all?/1` is calling under the hood.

Answer (score 7):

you could do `arr.compact.empty?`, `compact` gets rid of all the `nil` for you

you could read here at [ruby guides](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html) to find about all the methods on `Array` class