# How do I convert an entire nested hash (key and values) to lowercase?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a nested hash:

```
Hash = { "abc" => { "def" => { "count" => 120 } } ,
          "ABC" => {"DEF" => { "COUNT" => 100 } },
          "sample" => {"samplecode" => {"COUNT" => 3 } } }
```

I want to convert the entire hash into lowercase. If any duplicates exist, I want to add the count value. The resulting hash should be:

```
Result = { "abc" => { "def" => { "count" => 220 } } ,
            "sample" => { "samplecode" => { "count" => 3} } }
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: “I want to convert...”—don’t hesitate to do what you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we will be able to help you.

Comment: Post your code whatever you have tried. we are happy to assist you in resolving bugs/issues you encountered

Comment: This question's poster gets lambasted and downvoted, whilst another [poster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49665891/5101493) (moments earlier) has a few answers to his seemingly ill-researched question without any criticism or any downvoting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert hash keys to lowercase -- Ruby Beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980206/convert-hash-keys-to-lowercase-ruby-beginner)

Answer (score 0):

This would provide solution for your case: 
Next time it would be great if you could explain what method did you try and where did you face the issue in ..

```
result = {}
hash.each{|k,v|
  result[k.downcase] = result[k.downcase].present? ? result[k.downcase] : {}
  v.each{|key,values|
    result[k.downcase][key.downcase]= result[k.downcase][key.downcase].present? ? result[k.downcase][key.downcase] : {}
    values.each{|count, variable|
      result[k.downcase][key.downcase][count.downcase] = result[k.downcase][key.downcase][count.downcase].to_i + variable.to_i
    }
  }
}
```